# How to call a script function with same div name in php?

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
<p>Success login. You will be redirected in <span class="counter">10</span> second(s).</p>
<p>Wrong username/password. You will be redirected in <span class="counter">10</span> second(s).</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
function countdown() {
    var i = document.getElementByClassName('counter');
    if (parseInt(i.innerHTML)<=0) {
        location.href = 'login.php';
    }
    i.innerHTML = parseInt(i.innerHTML)-1;
}
setInterval(function(){ countdown(); },1000);
</script>
```

Before it was `id=counter`, and it works for one span tag. But I want two tags to share the same function. I tried changing it to `getElementByClassName` but it doesn't work. Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: `i` is going to be an array of matching nodes. Yo ucan't just `Array.innerHTML`...

Comment: Only one element should have the same `id` attribute value. The name of the method is `getElementsByClassName()` (plural on Element), because unlike the id attribute, many elements are allowed to have the same class name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no function `getElementByClassName()`, but just `getElementsByClassName()` (Note the plural for element**s**!). This returns a NodeList, which you then have to traverse:

```
function countdown() {
    var i = document.getElementsByClassName('counter');
    for( var j=0; j<i.length; j++ ) {
      if (parseInt(i[j].innerHTML)<=0) {
          location.href = 'login.php';
      }
      i[j].innerHTML = parseInt(i[j].innerHTML)-1;
    }
}
setInterval( countdown,1000);
```

PS: In your `setInterval()` you do not need a function expression - just give it a reference to the function itself (without calling it!).

Comment: I tried this but only one of the tags with the timer class works. The other one doesn't tick down. Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps my database is conflicting? I updated the code.

Comment: @Martynogea That is a different problem from the one before. Please explain the reasoning behind your (updated) code: what should it do?

Comment: Sorry I didn't know the query would affect it. I thought since the function works with one div - with or without query, and all I wanted it to work for two divs that share same class. Don't know why it stops working as it's working for the latter div.

Comment: @Martynogea I do not get, what your second SQL query should do. But anyway, the SQL problem is at PHP, whereas the other problem was in the JavaScript part. There is no direct connection here.

Comment: I'll try look into my database constraints, maybe that's causing the problem.

Comment: I've finally solved the problem. It was caused by the exit() function. :S 

I've accepted your answer as it solved my JS problem and it didn't affect the mysql of mine.

Answer (score 2):

`document.getElementsByClassName('counter')` **will return an array**.

*'getElements'* -  So to target an element in that array would be like :

`document.getElementsByClassName('counter')[0]`

or loop through them :

```
var counters = document.getElementsByClassName('counter');
for(var i=0, len=counters.length; i<len; ++i) {
  counters[i].innerHTML = 'I am content ' +i;
}
```

*Edit : - note the 'getElement **s** ByClassName' ( plural elements ) as others have pointed out*

Comment: Tested this one out too, but still got same problem "I tried this but only one of the tags with the timer class works. The other one doesn't tick down. Any ideas?"

Comment: Hi @Martynogea, if you update the question with your code so far , we can see what is going on now you have corrected the getELementsByClassName as an array.

Comment: Just updated the code* I get this error : Duplicate entry 'randomname-as@hotmail.com' for key 'username'

Answer (score -1):

There's no `getElementByClassName();` in Javascript. You should use `getElementsByTagName();`

Or, use jQuery selector `$('.counter');` (need jQuery library).

For more information, look at `[this][1]`.

Comment: Look here, by classname exists in modern browsers! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName